# pupil constrained to a surface

Tags: modeling

I want to break away from sphere based eyes where I can set the iris/pupil to constrain to a mesh ( which would have some roundness, just not a sphere), and can be moved around with a typical of tracking rig set up.

Anyone have a quick walk through?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

I will circle back around to polish the build instructions, but the things that make this work is adding a shrinkwrap constraint to the location of the empty (that is being rotated in the following animation), parenting the Iris/Pupil mesh to that Empty, and adding a shrinkwrap modifier to bend to the shape of the eyeball (the trick on this one is to set a small offset, and check keep above surface).

For an extra, I added a shapekey for the pupil dialation.

[image]

Comment: That's wonderful, thanks! But what if you wanted the iris to be concave, inward on that eyeball mesh?

Comment: Then you would probably want to parent something to the Iris/Pupil mesh that would perform a boolean difference to the eyeball, to punch a hole through it. Also instead of using the empty constrained to the eyeball, and parenting the Iris mesh to that, I found it better to set the origin of that mesh to the origin of the eyeball, and then on the Iris constraints, set a Track to the empty, so you can Aim it like normal (per your request).

Comment: @LoganMcNeil, you can also use shrinkwrap with a vertex group, and you can assign different weights values to the vertices in this group, so that they are more or less shrink to the surface. So, even if surely not perfect (or applicable to all cases) that allows to keep a volume to the iris