# Shrinkwraps Not Following Head - Pupil Shrinkwrap Not Staying On Eyes When Rotated

Tags: rigging, armature, constraints, tracking

This past week I've learned (sort of) how to set up an eye rig for non-spherical eyes using this incredible advice: [pupil constrained to a surface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50888/29865)

[image]

Basically, I have the **Eye** object. 
I have an **empty** object located *inside* the eye.
I have the **pupil** geometry parented to the **empty** object.

[image]

The **Pupil** has a *Shrinkwrap Modifier* applied, with the **Eye** as the target, giving the result in #1 in the picture.

The **Empty** object *inside* the eye has been given a *Shrinkwrap Constraint*, so it moves along the surface of the **Eye**. The **Pupil** object is parented to the **Empty** object with *Keep Offset* applied as the parent type, so the pupil doesn't deform as the pupil rotates around the eye.

The **Empty** object has a *Track To Constraint* applied to it, with a bone as the Target, see #2 in the picture.

When I rotate the head back, it looks like #3 and #4 in the picture.

I've tried parenting the pupil mesh to keep offset with the eye, parenting the empty to keep offset with the eye, and other random stuff that I can't exactly remember (because I wake up at 4:00AM to do this stuff before I go to work...).

*What are your ideas and solutions?*

If I'm going about it all wrong (this will eventually be going into Unity, so Lattice deformers are out of question, as Unity doesn't support Lattice deformation) then I'm willing to try a new approach. But right now, I can't turn or move the head from the default position without the eyes screwing up. If it stayed in this pose, it would work fine...

[image]

and here is the texture file

[image: penguin skin]

Comment: You mention that Unity doesn't support lattice deforms.  Does it support shrinkwrap?

Comment: @Nathan as far as I'm aware now, shrinkwrap is something that would have to be applied before it could be transferred over to Unity. I'm pretty sure any modifier has to be applied before it can be taken into Unity.

However, for this problem in particular, where I wanted to be able to animate the pupils, I think the best thing to do would be to animate the UVs or something. I never came back to this, and animated the character without eye animation. But it looks as if that would be the best go-to. No idea how to do it yet though.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't see the advantage in shrinkwrap over lattice-- both would have to be written to the mesh, or to a shapekey (I believe Unity calls them blendshapes.)

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I've learned a lot since then (including UV layouts, this is hideous lol)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Link to explain what I would change [image]

---

These are the primary things I felt I would change if this were my own.

---

I would use an Empty for the focal point (instead of a bone) and parent it to the armature.

I would get rid of the two empties at each pupil.

I would tell each pupil to track (constraint) to the "NEW" focal point empty.

I would tell each pupil to pivot (constraint) to the "Head" bone.

Here is the result of doing these four things.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and incredible solution. I'm at work right now so I can't get in Blender yet, but the changes sound reasonable to me! As long as the head is rotated in whatever direction and the pupils still follow the Target properly in all those directions the head is faced, I'm incredibly satisfied.

I'll take a look at it when I get home - can't wait. Many thanks again!

Comment: Wow it works! It's not flying everywhere now. But there are a couple problems with the pupil rotation... any way you know of around this?

https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7TKJqDiurP5aI9B6/giphy.gif

Comment: You could introduce two more empties that are parented to the main focal one, and have each pupil point to the corresponding one to each one of those. If the rotation seems off, you could rotate the main one enough to straighten it out. -Hope that helps

Comment: I'll give that a go.

Comment: Well having the extra eye control is nice; having each pupil look at their own empty, both pupil empties parented to the main one. Thanks for that tip. Also, rotating the empty in the x-axis, making it face more towards the head when it's lifted up and then moved side to side helps keep the pupils move in sync, so that's nice. Thanks.

I've fiddled with it a bit and still can't seem to fix that snapping that happens right when the eyes move past almost half-way up the eye. Don't suppose you have an idea of what's causing that? I can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: http://giphy.com/gifs/3oz8xt1h2RoY8HlJ16

Comment: Just curious, try rotating the Main Empty (the one you are moving) along the Z-Axis to aim at the centriod of the head (25°-45°), does that seem to solve it?

Comment: No, no difference, unfortunately.

Comment: By changing the "Pivot When" value, I get different jumping results. By changing it to "Always", it **works**! 


... except for one thing...


https://media.giphy.com/media/3oz8xCTAcn4EL9DoWs/giphy.gif

Comment: I've tried rotating it too when it gets to the point where it distorts. I wonder if it as something to do with the pivot loction/origin https://media.giphy.com/media/l3vR1EZTtxX3dQu64/giphy.gif

Comment: Ah hah! The geometry for the shrinkwrap os moving all over the place... How can this be solved? Simply origin, right...? Where would be the best spot for it? In the GIF, I'm simply moving the Empty only in the Z-Axis.
https://media.giphy.com/media/3oz8xJnAZyJHsGD4jK/giphy.gif

Comment: Here's my current .blend file: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1895" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1895/)

Comment: Let me know if this works, and I'll modify my answer to fit: [Updated Model](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1896/). I turned your pivot constraints off on the pupils, and Re-Adjusted your origins for both the eyes and the pupils. This seemed to solve a whole lot, because the rotation pivot becomes natural (not constrained). This might not be completely perfect, because the eyes are oblong (if they were true spheres a single point works well), but it seems to react a lot better anyhow.

Comment: That's fantastic. Works much better and cleaner. Yeah, it's not perfect at the top of the eye but I might be able to mess about with the pivot points.
Oh, except when I rotate the head back, we have the original problem again of the pupils not following the head... d'oh!

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have to call this unsolved because we ended up with the original problem again. I **really** appreciate the time and effort you gave previously. :)